# Get ContentTypeOrder of a specific folder using CAML and/or SharePoint web services

Tags: development, list, content-type, web-services

I am trying to get the `ContentTypeOrder` of a specific folder using SharePoint web services and caml queries. I am using the `GetListItems()` method of the `Lists.asmx` web service. The resulting xml contains the contentTypeId of the folder and doesn't say anything about the supported content types.

Is it possible to do it without the use of the SharePoint API and the SharePoint Client Object Model?

Do I need to add options to the caml query? Or use another web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it can't be done. The only solution is to create my own web service if I don't want to use the SharePoint API and the SharePoint client object model.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Lists web service, you could use the [GetListContentTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistcontenttypes%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method of that service. It probably does mean a second web service call.

Ignore the ContentTypeId parameter - it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm pretty sure that the content types are returned in content type order. What I'm not sure you can do is query a specific folder.

Comment: I can use the GetListContentTypes method but it returns the content types and the content type order on the root folder of a specified list. But i don't know to get the same information for other folders.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, that is tricky. I don't see a way of doing that via the web services. Perhaps add your own web service to SharePoint?

Comment: I was reading your blog http://www.novolocus.com/2007/12/08/the-circular-logic-of-the-wss-lists-webservice-getlistcontenttypes-call/ where you said that there is no easy way to identify non visible content types on a SharePoint list. Is there a way even if it is not easy? Can you look at another question similar to this? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26222/find-if-content-type-is-hidden-visible-is-not-checked-on-the-list-level-using

Comment: Hmm. Well, you could create your own web service to return that kind of information - that's what I mean by not easy.